# I am bit confused with function parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have following code in ext js

```
   form.submit({
                success: function(form, action) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                },
                failure: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                }
```

Is submit like a function which takes two parameter as argument or my understanding of it is incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

> is it lyk submit is a function which takes two parameter as argument
>   or my understanding of it is incorrect

No. `submit` is a function that accepts an `Object` as its parameter which may have `success` and `failure` methods.

It will be called like in this pseudo-code

```
function submit(obj) {
    if (some condition) {
        obj.success();
    } else obj.failure();
}
```

Comment: {
                success: function(form, action) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                },
                failure: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                } then what is this inside the submit

Answer (score 1):

as amit joki has told it was just a pseudo code if you really want to know about the code you can explore the Ext.form.Panel class.

It will basically send an ajax request to the url you have specified in your form panel config
and if call succeeds success function will be called else failure function will be called

say for example I have a form Objec:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    url: 'addProduct.jsp'
    ..
});

form.submit({
    success: function(form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
    }
});
```

when form.submit is executed it will send an ajax request to url specified while creating the form object here addProduct.jsp. if ajax call is succesful success callback function will be executed else
failure callback will be executed

here we have passed olny a single argument to submit function, which is an object and it has two properies success and failure...this has been already clarified by amit joki